# Dictionary Comprehension to Create New Columns in Stored DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary with values that are Pandas DataFrames. I would like to create new columns in each of the DataFrames. I could easily use a for loop, but I'd like a more pythonic way of doing it. Dictionary comprehensions seem like an ideal way to do it. How would this be done using dictionary comprehension?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data =[['2013',98],['2014',100],['2015',110],
                          ['2016',110],['2017',115]],
                   columns = ['Year','Value'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data =[['2013',85],['2014',90],['2015',95],
                          ['2016',97],['2017',99]],
                   columns = ['Year','Value'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data =[['2013',30],['2014',28],['2015',25],
                          ['2016',28],['2017',32]],
                   columns = ['Year','Value'])

d1 = {}
d1['df1'] = df1
d1['df2'] = df2
d1['df3'] = df3

for k in d1.keys():
    d1[k]['shifted'] = d1[k]['Value'].shift(2)
```

Comment: You don't want list/dict comprehensions because you'll be assigning something (a new column) to data frames and you can't *assign* inside a list comprehension. The simplest way I think of is having `dfs = [df1,df2,df3]` and a simple for loop `for df in dfs: df['shifted'] = df['Value'].shift(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a small helper function that is called within the dictionary comprehension:

```
def add_shifted_col(df):
    df['shifted'] = df['Value'].shift(2)
    return df

{k: add_shifted_col(v) for k, v in d1.items()}
```

EDIT: The dictionary comprehension creates a new dictionary. To update the original with this, you could call:

```
d1.update({k: add_shifted_col(v) for k, v in d1.items()})
```

This can be helpful if you only want to conditionally add extra Series to a selection of the dataframes e.g.

```
update_these = ['df2', 'df3']
d1.update({k: add_shifted_col(v) for k, v in d1.items() if k in update_these})
```

In this example, an extra series would be added to df2 and df3, but df1 would not be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate the extra example of conditionally selecting dataframes. I was hoping the dictionary comprehension would allow the use of functions without helper functions, but this solution works well and is quite read-able.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `concat` with `keys`

```
l=[df1,df2,df3]
newdf=pd.concat(l,keys=['df1','df2','df3'])
newdf['shifted']=newdf.groupby(level=0).Value.shift(2)
newdf
Out[437]: 
       Year  Value  shifted
df1 0  2013     98      NaN
    1  2014    100      NaN
    2  2015    110     98.0
    3  2016    110    100.0
    4  2017    115    110.0
df2 0  2013     85      NaN
    1  2014     90      NaN
    2  2015     95     85.0
    3  2016     97     90.0
    4  2017     99     95.0
df3 0  2013     30      NaN
    1  2014     28      NaN
    2  2015     25     30.0
    3  2016     28     28.0
    4  2017     32     25.0
```

Get df1

```
newdf.loc['df1']
Out[438]: 
   Year  Value  shifted
0  2013     98      NaN
1  2014    100      NaN
2  2015    110     98.0
3  2016    110    100.0
4  2017    115    110.0
```

Comment: I have a question. Thanks in advance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295160/pyspark-mapping-variables-from-different-dataframes @YOBEN_S